# Nodejs Ionic-Angular deployed to Heroku displays only the backend, instead of launching the whole app

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, heroku, deployment, procfile

My `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node src/app.js && ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "main": "src/app-routing.module.ts"
  },
```

1. I moved the `devdependencies` to `dependencies`.
2. Apps run locally with Heroku local web but display the only backend in the server.
3. Added a `procfile` containing `web: npm start`
4. Heroku assigns a port and the database is successfully connected. Backend works fine

My project structure: A `src/` folder that has both my back end and frontend files.

I guess I am losing out on the project structure. Please help to make me display the frontend of the app instead of backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay , 1)add the following to your app.js (or your server.js), and

app_path ='../www';

app.use('/api', songRoute)

app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,app_path)))

app.get('*',(req,res)=>res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,app_path + '/index.html')))

2)To package.json add this,

"heroku-postbuild":"ng build --configuration=production",